# Is $X=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2$ an invariance group of $SU(3)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

On page 7 of the following paper,

https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/1981031/339029.pdf

the author seems to imply that an expression of 6 independent variables such as:

$$
X = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2
$$

has invariance group SU(3).

Can anyone explain how the addition of six squares is related to SU(3).

In the case of SU(2), I can see that

$$
S=S_x\sigma_x + S_y\sigma_y + S_z\sigma_z\implies S^2 = S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2
$$

But su(2) is associated to 3 matrices and su(3) to 8 matrices. Why $X$ has 6 terms and not 8?

Comment: The question in your title is the wrong way around. Further, the "3" in $SU(3)$ stands for a $3$-dimensional complex vector space. That  is a six-dimensional real one, and it seems like the ariables $a, ..., f$ are intended to be real. Then again, the "S" in "SU" will lower one degree of freedom. -- Further, it seems like neither the paper nor you clearly distinguish between a group that leaves some form invariant and a group which consists of *exactly* the transformations which leave a certain form invariant (which for that form would be something like $O(6)$ or $SO(6)$).

Comment: If X  is a constant, your manifold is a 5-sphere, and [SU(3) acts transitively on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(3)).

Comment: You might, or might not, be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525166/visualization-of-su3), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2701566/manifold-of-su3-group).

Comment: My above comment might be a bit misleading as far as the number of variables of a form which is left invariant by a group has very little to do with the dimension of the group. So I should not even have mentioned the "degree-lowering" of the "S" in a sentence right after pointing out six variables of the form.